# Escaping a backslash in selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to escape a backslash into one of my selector :

```
if ( $("#\38 b13d5ea8c7081ff2ed6e34ab9d05ced > div.small-box.bg-red").hasClass("bg-red") ) {
    //do something it does have the protected class!
    console.log("i have the protected class");
}
```

Tried already :

```
#//\38 b13d5ea8c7081ff2ed6e34ab9d05ced > div.small-box.bg-red//

#//\38 b13d5ea8c7081ff2ed6e34ab9d05ced > div.small-box.bg-red//
```

but it doesn't fix the issue. Would appreciate your expertise.

Cheers!! , Marc

Additional informations :

I need to check if the "bg-red" class exists in one of the following div :

HTML

```
<div id="area4" class="col-sm-3 connectedSortable ui-sortable">

        <div id="8b13d5ea8c7081ff2ed6e34ab9d05ced" class="border-box">

                                    **<div class="small-box bg-red">**
                <div class="inner inner-box">
                    <p> </p>
                    <p>Veuillez svp saisir vos coordonnées<br><br></p>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="ion ion-person"></i>
                </div>
                <a href="/admin/mes_coordonnees/details" class="small-box-footer">Saisir mes coordonnées <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="action pull-right">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-componentid="8b13d5ea8c7081ff2ed6e34ab9d05ced" data-name="Small Box" class="btn-edit-component"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                &nbsp;
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-componentid="8b13d5ea8c7081ff2ed6e34ab9d05ced" class="btn-delete-component"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
            </div>
                    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML you're trying to control, or at least some of it, so that it's clearer what you're trying to do? Are you using the tag <#\38> ?

Comment: you have provided nothing for a help.

Comment: thanks @rob-kwasowski, I have added some additional infos.

Comment: thanks @adesh-kumar, I have added some additional infos.

Comment: what is this \31 in your selector. It's not here in your html

Comment: also use this as ('div .small-box').hasClass('bg-red') instead of ('div.small-box.bg-red').hasClass() . along with your main div id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 SOLUTIONS provided by

I forgot to import jquery in my blade file, after having done it, it works.

@adesh-kumar

```
 $('div .small-box').hasClass('bg-red')
```

@Jack-bashford

```
 $('#\\38 b13d5ea8c7081ff2ed6e34ab9d05ced').hasClass('bg-red');
```

Thanks both of you for your time and help.

A special thanks to the one who minus my question, that's really help, thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

Escape the backslash itself:

```
$("#\\38 ...")
```

Comment: Thanks @Jack-bashford, still the following error :
dashboards.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Make sure you import jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this once or let me know if anything else is required

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button").on('click',function(){
var a = $("div#8b13d5ea8c7081ff2ed6e34ab9d05ced div.small-box")
console.log(a)
if(a.hasClass("bg-red")){
alert("hii")
}
})


});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="button">Click to check class</button>
<div id="area4" class="col-sm-3 connectedSortable ui-sortable">

        <div id="8b13d5ea8c7081ff2ed6e34ab9d05ced" class="border-box">

                                    **<div class="small-box bg-red">**
                <div class="inner inner-box">
                    <p> </p>
                    <p>Veuillez svp saisir vos coordonnées<br><br></p>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="ion ion-person"></i>
                </div>
                <a href="/admin/mes_coordonnees/details" class="small-box-footer">Saisir mes coordonnées <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="action pull-right">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-componentid="8b13d5ea8c7081ff2ed6e34ab9d05ced" data-name="Small Box" class="btn-edit-component"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                &nbsp;
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-componentid="8b13d5ea8c7081ff2ed6e34ab9d05ced" class="btn-delete-component"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
            </div>
                    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```